# Checkable ListView or Pageable CheboxList ASP .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding

I need list view, that supports column with check boxes. Please help me add column with check boxes to ListView or add paging to CheckboxList

EDIT: I've forgot that also I need data bounding.
I've found out IPagedItemContainer interface and DataPager class. I need to add interface implementation to CheckboxList.
For Listview I haven't found any ideas on adding column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GridView with unvisible Header Row. And add a Checkbox Column.